# Bulk update lat/long taxonomy terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, location

I have Province/City taxonomy with 5000+ terms.

I would like to add lat/long field or something and bulk update whole taxonomy so i can use it later for maps and proximity search.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Geofield](https://drupal.org/project/geofield) and [Geocoder](https://drupal.org/project/geocoder) modules?

I believe you can configure the geofield as a field on your taxonomy to hold the Lat/Lng. Then, you can configure your geofield widget as `Geocode from another field`.

For batch back-filling, Geocoder provides the drush command:

```
geocoder-backfill     Geocodes all nodes that have a geocoder widget but no geodata.
```

Comment: Ill try both and tell you how it went. Unfortunately i do not know how to use drush. Any other way ?

Comment: Drush is your best bet; however, it may be possible with Views Bulk Operations (see https://drupal.org/node/1451942)